# Remove multiple spaces from variable values in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have bound my input box with `ng-modal="message"` and showing this `"message"` on at another place on HTML using `{{message}}`.

The issue is `{{message}}` remove all multiple spaces entered in text box.

Please find code https://jsfiddle.net/steinbring/kbwMY/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" ng-model="size" />
  <hr>
  <div style="font-size:{{size}}em;">{{message}}</div>
</div>
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 1st option (HTML tag)

Wrap your `{{message}}` in the `pre` tag:

```
<pre>{{message}}</pre>
```

## 2nd option (scope function)

Replace spaces with `&nbsp;` using a scope method:

```
$scope.cleanup = function(message) {
    return message.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
};
```

Now use in your HTML:

```
{{cleanup(message)}}
```

**See a working example below**

```js
angular.module("sa", []).controller("foo", function($scope, $sce) {
  
  $scope.cleanup = function(message) {
    message = message || '';
    
    // Need to trust as HTML to allow &nbsp; as HTML entity
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(message.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;'));
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="foo">
  <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" ng-model="size" />
  <hr>

  <!-- Need to now always use "ng-bind-html" -->
  <div style="font-size:{{size}}em;" ng-bind-html="cleanup(message)"></div>
</div>
```

---

## 3rd option (filter) - Recommended

Like [Pankaj Parkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2435473/pankaj-parkar) mentioned, you can create a filter as well:

```js
angular.module("sa", []).filter("allowWhiteSpace", function($sce) {
  
  return function(message) {
    message = message || '';
    
    // Need to trust as HTML to allow &nbsp; as HTML entity
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(message.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa">
  <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" ng-model="size" />
  <hr>

  <!-- Need to now always use "ng-bind-html" -->
  <div style="font-size:{{size}}em;" ng-bind-html="message | allowWhiteSpace"></div>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

## Even more, 4th Option (directive) - Recommended

You can make use of a directive:

```js
angular.module("sa", []).directive("allowWhiteSpace", function($sce) {

  return {
    scope: {
      value: '=allowWhiteSpace'
    },
    link: function($scope, element) {
      $scope.$watch('value', function(message) {
        message = message || '';

        return element.html(message.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;'));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa">
  <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" ng-model="size" />
  <hr>

  <div style="font-size:{{size}}em;" allow-white-space="message"></div>
</div>
```

## 5th Option (CSS)

Like [Utopic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1619406/utopik) mentioned, you can use [`white-space: pre;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) as well. This will work like the `<pre>` tag:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
    <input type="range"  min="1" max="100" ng-model="size" />
    <hr>
    <div style="font-size:{{size}}em; white-space: pre;">{{message}}</div>
</div>
```

Choice is yours :-)

Comment: let me try it @Shashank

Comment: @Shashank it would be better if you create a filter instead of function in scope.. so that would be reusable throughout application +1

Comment: you could also add some css `white-space: pre;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space +1 anyway